# How to Split a row into multiple columns from multi tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 2 table and They in a relationships:

```
select * from tableA,tableB
inner join tableA.id=tableB.id
```

and this query give me:

```
tableACol1  tableACol2 tableACol3  tableBCol1  tableBCol2 tableBCol3
a;b;c       1;2;3      t           x;y         8;9        p
```

and also i want do this :

```
col1 col2 col3 col3  col4  col5 col6  col6  col7  col8  col9 col10
a    1    b    2     c     3    t     x     8     y     9    p
```

My columns are dynamic.

How can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you always have at most 3 items for table A and 2 items for table B then you can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(a1, '[^;]+', 1, 1) AS col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(a2, '[^;]+', 1, 1) AS col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(a1, '[^;]+', 1, 2) AS col3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(a2, '[^;]+', 1, 2) AS col3,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(a1, '[^;]+', 1, 3) AS col4,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(a2, '[^;]+', 1, 3) AS col5,
       A3 AS col6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(b1, '[^;]+', 1, 1) AS col6,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(b2, '[^;]+', 1, 1) AS col7,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(b1, '[^;]+', 1, 2) AS col8,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(b2, '[^;]+', 1, 2) AS col9,
       B3 AS col10
FROM   your_query;
```

*Your column naming has been replicated in the output but it is better practice to name columns uniquely.*

Which, for the sample, data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_query (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3) AS
SELECT 'a;b;c', '1;2;3', 't', 'x;y', '8;9', 'p' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | 1 | b | 2 | c | 3 | t | x | 8 | y | 9 | p |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a461bfecd2fde3eaa43e23a0b1916bd6)*

---

If you have a variable number of columns then you would be best performing the transformation in whatever middle-tier language (i.e. C#, PHP, Java, C++)  you are using to access the database as SQL (not just Oracle SQL) must have a fixed number of known columns.

It is possible to use dynamic SQL within PL/SQL to programmatically generate an SQL statement and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` but I would not recommend it as it would be complicated and is likely to be much slower than performing the transformation in the middle tier.